# Geoserver, string parameter sending by using viewparams values

Tags: string, geoserver, sql-view, viewparams

Is it possible to send a string value to SqlView based layer in the `viewparameter` sequence? My parameter is similar to date (contains dashes) and if I put it in request like this:
http://x.y.z/geoserver/db/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=ABC:AnyDay&styles=&bbox=2069724.275423,7237025.845297,2069831.088769,7237123.162091&width=768&height=699&srs=EPSG:3857&format=image%2Fgif&viewparams=XYZ:2017-10-10

server gives error information: XYZ is integer and SQL query is bad - no layers appear.

I know this solution is dangeoreus but I have to agree with it.

Comment: please turn logging up to developer and then paste the relevant section of the log file into the question.

Answer (score 3):

As error given by geoserver. It seems variable XYZ is of integer type and you are passing argument non integer type. This type error came due to type mismatch.